# How to restart event mousemove jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousemove

I have to move a div by clicking on it, clicking again I must stop the div in that position. Now the problem is: when I want to move again the div, does not activate the mousemove event ... how can I fix it?

```
$('.move_div').live('click', function() {                    
    $('html').on('mousemove', function(e) {
       var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
       var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
       $('div').css({'top': y, 'left': x});
    });
    $("html").live('click', function() {
       $('html').off('mousemove');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/62Fmx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ele = '.move_adv';
var moveBool = false;

$(function () {
    $('html').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        console.log($(this).width());
        if (moveBool == true) {
            var x = e.pageX - $(ele).width()/2;
            var y = e.pageY - $(ele).height()/2;
            $(ele).css({
                'top': y,
                    'left': x
            });
        }
    });
});

$(ele).live('click', function () {
    moveBool = !moveBool;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6y24s/2/

The main logic is storing the 'moveability' state of the div in a boolean.

You would also like to refine the code more.

Comment: yep, the click don't stop the mousemove event in firefox and internet explorer

Comment: Updated the answer and cleaned up the code. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/62Fmx/2/) , if you want to keep your code then only thing you need to add is

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: i try but not work, the click of the mouse must start and stop the movement of the div

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the div the mousemove handler is added to the div. Then an event handler is added to the document that removes any mousemove event handlers.
You then move the mouse and the div follows, you click and the mousemove handler is deleted.
You click on the div again, a mousemove event handler is added, though then the click event handler from the document takes away the mousemove handler.
So whenever you click after the first two clicks the mousemove handler is simultaneously created and destroyed.

Also use .on() instead of .live()
.live() was deprecated in JQuery 1.7